# Complex pivot of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file from an external provider which looks like below.

```py
Minute Splits    5    10    15    20
John             NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN      
Total            10   12    15    10
Walking          3    4     5     6
Jogging          3    3     4     2
Sprinting        4    5     6     2
NaN              NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
Peter            NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
Total            12   14    10    8
Walking          5    10    4     6
Jogging          4    2     4     2
Sprinting        3    2     2     0
NaN              NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
Michael          NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
Total            15   12    16    8
Walking          12   6     8     5
Jogging          2    4     4     2
Sprinting        1    2     4     1
```

I want to pivot/transform the dataframe like below.
I have included a csv example to test in this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qUGMD3gR0A2cY5e3cWJmHhvItiWUSzS9ZCEpOcc4I78/edit?usp=sharing)

```py
Player  MinuteSplits  Total Walking  Jogging  Sprinting
John    5             10             3        4
John    10            12             3        5
John    15            15             4        6
John    20            10             2        2
Peter   5             12             4        3
Peter   10            14             2        2
Peter   15            10             4        2
Peter   20            8              2        0
Michael 5             15             2        1
Michael 10            12             4        2
Michael 15            16             4        4
Michael 20            8              2        0
```

Any help is highly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Select then stack ?

Comment: Could you maybe specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do `stack` after `reset_index`

```
df['name'] = df.MinuteSplits.where(df['5'].isna()).ffill()
out = df.set_index(['name','MinuteSplits']).stack().unstack(level=1).reset_index()
out
Out[695]: 
MinuteSplits     name level_1  Total  Walking  Jogging  Sprinting
0                John       5   10.0      3.0      3.0        4.0
1                John      10   12.0      4.0      3.0        5.0
2                John      15   15.0      5.0      4.0        6.0
3                John      20   10.0      6.0      2.0        2.0
4             Michael       5   15.0     12.0      2.0        1.0
5             Michael      10   12.0      6.0      4.0        2.0
6             Michael      15   16.0      8.0      4.0        4.0
7             Michael      20    8.0      5.0      2.0        1.0
8               Peter       5   12.0      5.0      4.0        3.0
9               Peter      10   14.0     10.0      2.0        2.0
10              Peter      15   10.0      4.0      4.0        2.0
11              Peter      20    8.0      6.0      2.0        0.0
```